# Autofill Destination not the same range size

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

Trying to find solution for simple Autofill Macro until the last row. I got error that all merged cells must need to be the same size.

```
Sub Button10_Click()
    Sheets("P").Select
    Range("P5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "5"
    LastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("P5").Select
   Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("P5:P" & LastRow)  (error row)
Sheets("Test").Select
End Sub
```

Maybe someone know where can be a problem?

Comment: The problem sounds like merged cells. They are generally a nuisance, and unnecessary. Get rid of them!

Comment: Try this one line `Range("P5:P" & LastRow).Value = 5` instead of the Autofill

Comment: Siddharth Rout thanks, smart solution!

Comment: You can get rid of all your code including `.Select` The one liner will take care of it. [Interesting Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)